# How to create genbank flat file

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I am having hard time creating a genbank flat file using Biopython SeqIO (into something like http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/CP003206) 
I was able to create a genbank by doing

```
simple_seq = Seq(row[15],IUPAC.unambiguous_dna)
simple_seq_r = SeqRecord(simple_seq)
simple_seq_r.id=row[0]
simple_seq_r.description= 'hello' 
SeqIO.write([seqrecord],'out.gbk', "gb")
```

But I was unable to write to the following fields because seqrecord does not have fields for these: 
KEYWORDS 
SOURCE
DBLINK
ORGANISM
FEATURES
Location/Qualifiers

Would you know how do this? Thanks

Comment: you should ask biostars http://www.biostars.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SeqRecord class should have these fields in the following attributes:

- **dbxrefs** contains a string with database cross references (DBLINK): 'BioProject:PRJNA42399'.
- **annotations** is another dictionary that contains many values including the keywords (annotations['keywords']), such as: comment, taxonomy, organism, accesions.
- **features** contains the features as a list of instances of SeqFeature class.

For further info you can read the SeqRecord class wiki: http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqRecord, and the SeqFeature reference page: http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqFeature.SeqFeature-class.html

Another thing you can do is to save this genbank file you provided and read it with SeqIO, then use dir() to see which are the actual attributes you can use and in the case of attributes that are stored as dictionaries, it is useful to see the keys. Something like this (where my_file.gbk contains a subsequence of the file you provided):

```
my_record = SeqIO.read('my_file.gbk', 'gb')
print "DBXREFS: ", my_record.dbxrefs
print "ANNOTATIONS: ", my_record.annotations.keys()
print "FEATURES: ", my_record.features
```

would give you some further info about the file you provided:

```
DBXREFS:  ['BioProject:PRJNA42399 BioSample:SAMN02603066']
ANNOTATIONS:  ['comment', 'sequence_version', 'source', 'taxonomy', 'keywords', 'references', 'accessions', 'data_file_division', 'date', 'organism', 'gi']
FEATURES:  [SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(ExactPosition(0), ExactPosition(1001), strand=1), type='source'), SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(BeforePosition(0), ExactPosition(471), strand=1), type='gene'), SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(BeforePosition(0), ExactPosition(471), strand=1), type='CDS')]
```

Comment: If this answered your question, could you accept it? :) If not, maybe is there anything that is not clear in it? Thanks!